# outputting detailed errors in php

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

Ive gone through my php.ini and turned on error reporting, now my errors get outputted like this

[image: my php errro]

But watching tutorials online ive seen peoples errors displayed like this

[image]

How can i enable detailed error reporting like that ?

Comment: They are using some debugger. Google `PHP Debugger`

Comment: that's probably xdebug. quite useless thing, as on a live server you can't use all these bells and whistles anyway

Comment: Not useless at all. It's actually VERY useful while you're developing your PHP application in your development server, as you get a complete call stack trace so you can easily find the line which causes the error, not just the last line when the error was actually triggered. A professionally developed site shouldn't be edited directly in the live server anyway, but in the copy in the development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension called **XDebug**. You need to download the Xdebug DLL and enable with your setup. Then this will give the error messages in the shown form.

For more details visit [XDebug](http://xdebug.com/)